# AWS Lambda execution model (threading?)

Tags: java, aws-lambda

I am having sample test which invokes lambda function via client build like this:

```
LambdaInvokerFactory.builder
    .lambdaClient(AWSLambdaClientBuilder.defaultClient)
    .build(classOf[HelloLambdaClient])
```

Whenever I perform synchronous executions in a row and **my lambda initializes on start random variable**. This random value is printed in Lambda response (look below). Lambda code has sleep which makes it execute ~ 2s. Here is the output:

> Success returned from request: b3059f87-50f1-11e7-9f5d-ed6e02ee1217.  Random value is: 5861335772453319884 remaining ms: 28498 ms VALUE IS: 10
>   Success returned from request: b3f41e37-50f1-11e7-82fb-3750155d81e4. Random value is: 5861335772453319884 remaining ms: 28498 ms VALUE IS: 11
>   Success returned from request: b4e4243d-50f1-11e7-8abb-ad83d8f0c65c. Random value is: 5861335772453319884 remaining ms: 28498 ms VALUE IS: 12
>   Success returned from request: b5d33eef-50f1-11e7-b89a-79ba5c4113d5. Random value is: 5861335772453319884remaining ms: 28498 ms VALUE IS: 13
>   Success returned from request: b6c31caf-50f1-11e7-86ab-cd495fa85bb3. Random value is: 5861335772453319884remaining ms: 28498 ms VALUE IS: 14
>   Success returned from request: b7b322bc-50f1-11e7-b7a3-f789b1e8355b.

It's clearly visible that we have same JVM, same class responding to each and every request (random value is always the same).

Now however if I add some async calls (`InvocationType=Event`) in between these calls - thus effectively having many concurrent calls, the output starts to change like here:

> Success returned from request: 1dd4caca-50ef-11e7-8a78-83ef7e890b67. Random value is: -18127642905056328 remaining ms: 28498 ms VALUE IS: 21
>   Success returned from request: 1ec45ae6-50ef-11e7-b7ed-a77459f1846a. Random value is: -18127642905056328 remaining ms: 28498 ms VALUE IS: 22
>   Success returned from request: 1fb54a81-50ef-11e7-94d2-97694951faa1. Random value is: -18127642905056328 remaining ms: 28498 ms VALUE IS: 23
>   Success returned from request: 20b3332a-50ef-11e7-b99e-0955a3fdf5d0. Random value is: 663265193956577535 remaining ms: 28498 ms VALUE IS: 7

(last call above ended up on another lambda instance then the previous ones).

It's pretty much reproducible every time I do concurrent calls.

Questions:

- Is it a know feature of AWS Lambda that concurrent calls are routed to different Lambda instances?
- Does AWS Lambda give you similar single-thread guarantees as e.g. `Akka` gives you for actors (while you are processing message you are guaranteed to be in `thread-safe` environment - at least until you introduce multithreading by yourself)?

Answer (score 0):

AWS Lambda is meant to run at scale. Therefore, if there is no free, running instance of a Lambda, AWS will start a new instance. This is effectively what you see in your concurrent execution. Lambda functions are stateless and there is no guarantee that two subsequent requests will call the same instance of a Lambda function.

> Concurrency is the number of requests that your function is serving at any given time. When your function is invoked, Lambda provisions an instance of it to process the event. When the function code finishes running, it can handle another request. If the function is invoked again while a request is still being processed, another instance is provisioned, increasing the function's concurrency. [Source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-concepts.html#gettingstarted-concepts-concurrency)

You can set the allowed concurrency in your Lambda function [(Source)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-features.html#gettingstarted-features-concurrency).

If you need to preserve some state across the processing or need to process messages in a certain order, have a look into [Step Functions](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions), [Kinesis](https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis), or [SQS](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/).